# Java development on Windows, run on Raspberry Pi Ref Lib Not Found

Tags: java, freetts

I've been searching for an answer all night and morning and I'm almost about to give up. I was hoping someone here has had the same problem has and has figured it out.

Basically, I've developed a project on Windows using Eclipse and I would like to run it on my Raspberry Pi. Of course it's no problem, normally, but I'm trying to use a library.

The library is FreeTTS. It works fine on Windows but when I go to use it on my Pi, it can't find the location of the library. I've tried everything and my brain in fried.

The structure of my project is:
bin - compiled classes
src - source files
lib - libraries (include freetts.jar)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/speech/freetts/VoiceManager

In Eclipse, I have the libs connected to the project relatively.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the command you're executing to run your program on the Pi?

Comment: What sort of manifest file do you have?

Comment: @Boann I've tried all of the following, and more combinations:
java -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/BPi/lib -classpath /home/pi/BPi/bin com.brandonmxb.bpi.Main
java -classpath /home/pi/BPi/bin com.brandonmxb.bpi.Main
sudo java -cp lib/freetts.jar com.brandonmxb.bpi.Main

Comment: @HovercraftFullofEels (I like your name) I'm not specifying any specific manifest. Just some JARS that go with FreeTTS and some of my own classes.

Comment: What about `java -cp bin:lib/freetts.jar com.brandonmxb.bpi.Main` ? By the way Wikipedia says FreeTTS is dead (?)

Comment: Yes! The whole time I didn't notice I was using "." as the current path which made no sense. I just spent almost 7 hours trying to figure this out, while my brain melted. And hearing my program FINALLY working. Haha thank you so much! You answered my question. :)

Comment: Oh, okay! I'll post that as an answer below then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the directory containing bin and lib, your command should look like:

```
java -cp bin:lib/freetts.jar com.brandonmxb.bpi.Main
```

That puts both the bin directory and the jar on the classpath, separated by `:` (`;` on Windows).

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly! Saved me from more headaches :) To readers: This was a question to do with running your program with certain libraries, not about FreeTTS. :D